# Transform capital font letters in small caps for every post

Tags: mysql, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with 600 posts, I'd like to transform for each post the capital letters that appear like that for example "NEDC" in small caps font variant.

I know how to batch modify HTML tags in a database but in this particular case I will have to find another solution. It should scan all the text and look for a succession of characters that are in capital letters and insert a class so I can control the font style.

Is this something possible?

Comment: try applying the small cap font-variant with an `!important` to your posts and see if you're happy with the outcome

Comment: text-transform:lowercase;

Comment: Are you looking for a client-side solution, as the “css” tag suggests? CSS can’t be used for this; you need JavaScript that detects sequence of uppercase letters. CSS can then rather trivially be used to render them in **false** small caps with `font-variant: small-caps` or, with considerable limitations and nontrivial effort, as real small caps when present in the font used.